# nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to setup a server with nginx and docker-compose, but I get these errors every time I try 'docker-compose up':

```
webserver | 2019/06/10 13:04:16 [emerg] 1#1: "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1
webserver | nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1
```

I've tried wrapping all up with html {}, removing server {}, another port instead of 80...

nginx Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://app:8080/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Remote into the container and check all of your files make sure the right files are in the right place with the expected content.

Comment: I cant even do that because container won't start after those errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when you are trying to overwrite the default nginx config file which does not accept some root properties like `http`, `user`. If you need those extra configurations you can try copying what you have to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

So instead of this: `COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

Do this: `COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

> Note: By copying to the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`, you will be overwriting the default config.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to add another solution to the ones proposed above. As above suggested, substituting `nginx.conf` or `default.conf` works. I do it in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
    volumes:
      - ./services/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**However**, I came across the **necessity to use environment variables** in my `nginx.conf` file, which requires creating a template in `/etc/nginx/templates/`, which `envsubst` then outputs in  `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, like explained [here](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/nginx#using-environment-variables-in-nginx-configuration).

I came across the following errors:

- `nginx: [emerg] "events" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`
- `nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

Here is the working solution for the `nginx.conf` file (the file name does not matter here, since it is changed when copied to container, see docker-compose below, but I like to name it nginx.conf for clarity):

```
server {
  listen ${FE_PORT};
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend:${FE_PORT};
  }
}
server {
  listen ${BE_PORT};
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend:${BE_PORT};
  }
}
server {
  listen ${SERVICE_PORT};
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://service:${SERVICE_PORT};
  }
}
```

And `docker-compose.yml`:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "${FE_PORT}:${FE_PORT}"
      - "${BE_PORT}:${BE_PORT}"
      - "${SERVICE_PORT}:${SERVICE_PORT}"
    environment:
      - FE_PORT
      - BE_PORT
      - SERVICE_PORT
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by overwrting nginx.conf.

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

default.conf

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream app {
        server app:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://app;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }

}
```